# jQuery simplemodal plugin: the method close() is causing error

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, simplemodal

when trying to close the simplemodal dialog, as I see in the plugin's website examples, it is done by calling

```
$.modal.close() or modal.close()
```

But non of them worked for me.

On Chrome console I get this:

`Uncaught TypeError: Object #<an HTMLDivElement> has no method 'close'
$.live.$.load.$.modal.onClose`

Here is the full code.

```
$('.FinishUploadedFile').live('click',function(){

        $('<div id="modal"></div>').load('page?n=3',function(){

            $(this).modal({
                overlayClose: true,
                position: ['10%'],
                overlayOpacity:0,
                onOpen: function (dialog) {
                    dialog.overlay.fadeIn('normal', function () {
                        dialog.data.hide();
                        dialog.container.fadeIn('fast', function () {
                            dialog.data.slideDown('fast');
                        });
                    });
                },
                onClose: function (dialog) {
                    dialog.data.fadeOut('normal', function () {
                        dialog.container.slideUp('fast', function () {
                            dialog.overlay.fadeOut('fast', function () {
                                //Close the dialog.
                                modal.close();
                            });
                        });
                    });
                }
            });

        });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't declared `modal` anywhere. You'll need to change `modal.close();` to `$.modal.close();` or change your `onClose` function to:

```
onClose: function (dialog) {
    var modal = this; // <- add this line
    dialog.data.fadeOut('normal', function () {
        dialog.container.slideUp('fast', function () {
            dialog.overlay.fadeOut('fast', function () {
                //Close the dialog.
                modal.close();
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi Eric, thanks. Finally opted for the `$.modal.close();` solution